# Custom data field - problem with import

Tags: custom-fields, import

I have to import small quantity of contacts with custom date field. Field is set as rrrr (which should be filled with 4-digits year - 2017). Every single time, when this year is added in csv file I've got error 'Invalid value for field(s)'.

Value is set as 2015.

What may be the cause of that?

Comment: i think you need to import as eg 2015-01-01. also what do you mean by rrrr. is that a typo for yyyy?

Comment: Yes, I ment yyyy  (rrrr is symbol in my language :)) I've just check database for this value that is being saved when I type 2015 and it is saved as '2015-01-01 00:00:00'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

petednz - fuzion was right. Type of data that can be selected during custom field setup is related to data. display, not to data type. Database needs full date (even if field was setup as yyyy). Adding 01-01 helped.